# Pine Script - Alert function being called yet alert not sent

Tags: pine-script

I have a strategy that's being calculated on every tick and it has 2 alerts below 2 separate if statements. Both of these statements come true (strategy functions normally within pine, and displays label.new -s at correct time and price), yet only the first alert is sent.

I have simplified the conditions and tried to reproduce the error to no avail, it produced 2 alarms as it should:

alert("1",alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)

if barstate.isconfirmed

alert("2",alert.freq_once_per_bar)

My question: is there something fundamental I'm missing? I have a PRO account and 10 of these strategies are running in parallel, producing 10 alert "1" -s every bar close, but sometimes alert "2" is triggered when there should be 10+ alerts sent out.
I suspected barstate.isconfirmed and calculate_on_every tick doesn't like each other, but the simplified version works just fine.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Any chance you're reaching the [limit](https://www.tradingview.com/support/solutions/43000481368-strategy-alerts/) of max 15 alerts per 3 minutes?

Comment: Good point, ill have to have a workaround for that in the future, but i think it isn't the problem now, otherwise i could have 10-15 alarms, but I only have the 10 "1" -s now.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.